# Dealing with missing values?

Tags: r, regression, self-study, missing-data

I have a data set that contains the prices of 1000 UPC items in 17 different supermarkets. The problem is that the same 1000 items are not in all 17 stores. On average, only 10 of the stores have a given item. I'm wondering how to approach this (note- I'm trying to estimate the pricing premium for each of the 17 supermarkets using regression.)

I figure I can drop some items that are relatively rare, or impute missing values, or run an unbalanced design of some kind. What would you recommend and why?

Comment: "I'm trying to estimate the pricing premium for each of the 17 supermarkets using regression." Can you describe your regression approach in more detail? To me it appears you should simply use a mixed effects model with the supermarkets as subjects. You could then simply use the fixed effects part of the model (the "population mean effect") for those supermarkets that don't offer an item.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of missing items and the number of auxiliary variables you could do multiple imputation with for example the package `mice`

Comment: Why do you recommend this? I wouldn't even call what Blake describes "missing values".

Comment: Why would it not be missing?

Comment: The distinction I'm trying to make is: Was the item on offer but the price not recorded or was the item not on offer. If the latter, you absolutely should not impute it because this item being on offer or not might have an impact on the prices of other products.

Comment: So, a value can be considered missing if the underlying observation exists.